# Data not appending to file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to appending emails that have signup'd to a csv file, but it shows success, whereas there is nothing in the file, nothing is appending and when i print_r the `fwrite` it says 15

This is my code

```
  <form action="send.php" method="post"  name="newsletter" class="">
                            <label class="sr-only">Email:</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control rounded-right bg-transparent" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;">
                                    <button type="submit" class="home-signup-email-btn btn btn-blue btn-lg ml-3 rounded py-0">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                        </form>

  $email = $_POST['email'];
//$filename = 'suscribers.txt';
//$somecontent = "$email\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.

$txt = '/n'.$_POST['email'].'/n';
$file = fopen('mailing_list.csv','a');
if (fwrite($file,$txt)){


// fwrite($file,$txt);
$message= "Success!. You have been added to our email list.";
$status  = "success";
$data = array(
            'status'  => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );

        echo json_encode($data);}
        else
            echo "fail";
```

Comment: first try using text file

Comment: It didn't work too

Comment: check $_POST revives data or not?

Comment: it does, i echoed the $txt variable, the email showed

Comment: Am i meant to make the file writtable

Comment: And when i print_r the fwrite it says 15

Comment: use $file = fopen('mailing_list.csv','a+');

Comment: Not stilll working

Comment: use below code I pasted in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173257/discussion-between-dinesh-ghule-and-iruene-adokiye).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution it wasn't writing to the file because i didn't add an `fclose` to close the `fopen`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Make sure your file is in the same directory or specify path

Answer (score 0):

Use a+ mode:

Open a file for read/write. The existing data in file is preserved. File pointer starts at the end of the file. Creates a new file if the file doesn't exist

```
<form action="send.php" method="post"  name="newsletter" class="">
                                <label class="sr-only">Email:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control rounded-right bg-transparent" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;">
                                        <button type="submit" class="home-signup-email-btn btn btn-blue btn-lg ml-3 rounded py-0">Sign Up</button>
                                    </div>
                            </form>

      $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.

    $txt = '/n'.$_POST['email'].'/n';
    $file = fopen('mailing_list.txt','a+');
    if (fwrite($file,$txt)){

    $message= "Success!. You have been added to our email list.";
    $status  = "success";
    $data = array(
                'status'  => $status,
                'message' => $message
            );

            echo json_encode($data);

             fclose($file);
            chmod($file, 0777); 
        }else {
         echo "fail"; 
          }
```